# How set "Inherit schema from table" for glue crawler via cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

`Schema change policy` section in web colsole for aws glue crawler contains 3 points while cloudformation section  template defines only 2. Is there a way to set  "Inherit schema from table" parameter from cloudformation template?

[image: Cloudformation spec vs web console]

Answer (score 4):

Update: as of August 23rd 2018, you can now set the Configuration via CloudFormation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-crawler.html#cfn-glue-crawler-configuration

---

Currently there does not appear to be any way to set the Configuration attribute that stores this setting (see the [API Documentation for Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html)).

You can use boto3 (or other SDKs) to update the Configuration attribute. It takes a JSON string like this:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('glue')
>>> client.update_crawler(Name='CrawlerName',Configuration='{"Version": 1.0, "CrawlerOutput": { "Partitions": { "AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable" } } }')
```

I verified after doing this that the option is selected in the UI, and returned when retrieving the Crawler information via boto3 or the CLI. It should be possible to write a lambda function and use it as a custom resource to do this update via CloudFormation (I'm currently evaluating Glue/Athena, and hit this same problem).

Answer (score 3):

The "Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table" option in the AWS Console corresponds to setting `CrawlerOutput.Partitions.AddOrUpdateBehavior: InheritFromTable` in the Crawler API `Configuration` field, as noted in the ["Configuring a Crawler"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html) documentation.

Unfortunately, it seems that CloudFormation hasn't yet been updated to support setting the `Configuration` attribute in the [`AWS::Glue::Crawler`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-crawler.html) Resource. Until CloudFormation's resource implementation catches up to a more recent Glue API revision, the only way to update this via CloudFormation is to deploy a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) invoking a Lambda Function that invokes the `glue.updateCrawler` API with a `Configuration` JSON parameter directly. You'll also need an IAM Role with a policy granting permissions to the `glue.updateCrawler` action.

Here's a full custom-resource implementation that will update the Configuration on an existing `Crawler` resource:

```
  GlueConfigurationLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Adjusts Glue Configuration property.
      FunctionName: GlueConfiguration
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt GlueConfigurationRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const response = require("cfn-response");
          const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
          const glue = new AWS.Glue();
          exports.handler = function (event, context) {
            console.log("Request received:\n", JSON.stringify(event));
            let physicalResourceId = event.ResourceProperties.CrawlerName;
            const respond = (e) => response.send(event, context, e ? response.FAILED : response.SUCCESS, e ? e : {}, physicalResourceId);
            process.on('uncaughtException', e=>respond(e));
            try {
              let configuration = (event.RequestType === 'Create' || event.RequestType === 'Update') ?
                event.ResourceProperties.Configuration :
                {};
              if (configuration.Version) {
                configuration.Version = parseFloat(configuration.Version);
              }
              glue.updateCrawler({
                Name: physicalResourceId,
                Configuration: JSON.stringify(configuration)
              }).promise()
                .then(data=>respond())
                .catch(e=>respond(e));
            } catch (e) { respond(e); }
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
  GlueConfigurationRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal: {Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]}
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: GluePolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 'glue:UpdateCrawler'
              Resource: '*'
  CrawlerConfiguration:
    Type: Custom::CrawlerConfiguration
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt GlueConfigurationLambda.Arn
      CrawlerName: !Ref Crawler
      Configuration:
        Version: '1.0'
        CrawlerOutput:
          Partitions:
            AddOrUpdateBehavior: InheritFromTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a crawler configuration option to `InheritFromTable`.
This option is named `Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table` on the AWS Glue console.

When this option is set, partitions inherit metadata properties such as their classification, input format, output format, serde information, and schema from their parent table. Any change in properties to the parent table are propagated to its partitions. When this configuration option is set on an existing crawler, existing partitions are updated to match the properties of their parent table the next time the crawler runs.

Source: [Glue-CreateCrawler-request-Configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_CreateCrawler.html#Glue-CreateCrawler-request-Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Configuration property to set "Inherit schema from table" via CloudFormation. I've tried this and it worked for me.

```
"Type": "AWS::Glue::Crawler",
"Properties": {
   "Configuration": "{ \"Version\": 1.0, \"CrawlerOutput\": {\"Partitions\": { \"AddOrUpdateBehavior\": \"InheritFromTable\" }}}"
}
```

For details on "Configuration" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html